# EntityManager#getResultList() returns an empty list

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm working on my first web shop and have trouble to retrieve objects when searching for them. Searching for an existing product results in that the list productHits remains empty.

(To read the whole project please see https://github.com/gitsjogren/TareaWebShop)

Here's the product catalogue:

```
public final class ProductCatalogue extends AbstractDAO<Product, Long> implements IProductCatalogue {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("shop_pu");
    private static Product p1;
    private static Customer c1;

@Override
    public List<Product> search(String searchWord){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<Product> prodHits = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.name LIKE :theSearch";
            TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(sqlQuery, Product.class);
            String searchQuery = "%" + searchWord + "%";
            q.setParameter("theSearch", searchQuery);
            prodHits = (List<Product>) q.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        em.close();
        return prodHits;
}
```

I have also tried using a NativeQuery instead of a TypedQuery, with no luck.

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, Product.class);
```

Comment: your query seems correct, probably no data. just test the same with native query

Comment: The query string used is native SQL, but you are using createQuery which expects a JPQL string and doesnt take the entity class as a parameter, I'm not sure why you don't get an exception.  Are you using createNativeQuery?  If so, then check the database has data.  It could be the login credentials used for the JPA app are not going to the database with the data.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an exception? You have the `catch` statement-- is anything being printed? Have you tried debugging? You can fix the original JPQL query by simply changing the `*` to `p`.

Comment: I'm not getting any message in the console when I do a search. The connection to the database seem to be fine since I can recieve all the products through another method in the same class that is using a TypedQuery with the string "select p from product p".

Answer (score 2):

**If you're didn't get your answer yet:**

it can happen when you have something uncommitted on that table in DB. In that case, if you run the same query in DB you'd get the real answer, but if you run it from the code, it may return empty list.